# Using array of boost range_iterator to split a string

Tags: c++, boost, range

i would like to process an undefinitely long string in C++ by chunks of a given fixed length (e.g. 15 chars).

The string is an attribute of the class in charge of processing it (let's call the class "Person" and the attribute "_description"), and external code must call a method to process each chunk sequentially, e.g. Person::processDescription(). Another method allows to see if there is one more chunk to process, e.g. Person::isThereMoreDescriptionToBeProcessed().

In order to avoid dealing with indexes and possible side effects (errors with +1/-1, init..), someone suggested me to store an array of range_iterators (boost) and iterate over them for processing, but I don't know the range_iterator concept and Boost docs did not help too much here.

I guess I will store 2 items (e.g. _currentItem and _endItem) as attributes of Person and do a check like

```
_currentItem == _endItem
```

in isThereMoreDescriptionToBeProcessed() and I guess I will do something like

```
_currentItem++
```

at the end of processDescription(), but I can't understand how I can populate the array of range iterator at the init of the _description property for this purpose and how can i get the string to be processed in processDescription().

Thanks for throwing some lights on this.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to avoid dealing with indices or what the side effects you're worried about.

Comment: it is quite a delicate code, that will be probably maintained by other people in the future. initialization and cycling over indexes is one of the most common sources of errors. they can cause severe problems that are really difficult to root cause.

why shouldn't I try find out a smart way, closer to an object-oriented approach, to work this around? someone suggested me a way to do this, i am just trying to figure out how i can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given two iterators that you want to create a range out of, you would just construct a `boost::iterator_range` and pass the two iterators as constructor arguments.

The below code splits `str` into three character segments and pushes each segment into `ranges`.

```
std::vector<boost::iterator_range<std::string::iterator>> ranges;
std::string str = "abcdefghijk";

auto it = str.begin();
auto lastIt = it;
while (it != str.end())
{
    lastIt = it;
    if (std::distance(it, str.end()) < 3)
        it = str.end();
    else
        std::advance(it, 3);

    ranges.push_back(
        boost::iterator_range<std::string::iterator>(lastIt, it)
    );
}

for (auto segment = ranges.begin(); segment != ranges.end(); ++segment)
    std::cout << std::string(segment->begin(), segment->end()) << std::endl;
```